# Pass anonymous struct as parameter in C

Tags: c, function, struct, parameters

I have the following line of c (carriage returns added for readability - they aren't in the code):

```c
#define i2c_write(slave_addr, reg_addr, len, *data_ptr)
    twi_master_write(MPU_TWI, {
        .addr = reg_addr,
        .addr_length = 1,
        .buffer = *data_ptr,
        .length = len,
        .chip = slave_addr
    })
```

Where `twi_master_write()` is declared as:

```c
uint32_t twi_master_write(Twi *p_twi, twi_packet_t *p_packet);
```

and `twi_packet_t` is declared as:

```c
typedef struct twi_packet {
    uint8_t addr[3];
    uint32_t addr_length;
    void *buffer;
    uint32_t length;
    uint8_t chip;
} twi_packet_t;
```

The parameters of `twi_write()` are all required to be of type `unsigned char`.

When compiling, I receive the following error:

```
expected expression before '{' token
```

Is there a correct way to do what I'm trying to do here, or is it just not possible?

Comment: `error: "*" may not appear in macro parameter list`… and can you show the usage of the macro?

Comment: Here's an example usage: `i2c_write(st.hw->addr, st.reg->pwr_mgmt_1, 2, data)`.  This is a [link](https://github.com/spacelan/MyBoard/blob/612474b4d18bb555047fd6a7562080baa32aed18/HARDWARE/eMPL/inv_mpu.c) to a copy of the code where `i2c_write` is used.

Comment: @mafso Also, that error you quoted does not appear for me.  The `typedef` already exists in the code (ie. it wasn't written by me).

Comment: I wasn't talking about the `typedef` but about the macro: `#define i2c_write(slave_addr, reg_addr, len, *data_ptr) ...`—this isn't allowed in C.

Comment: This line (`#define i2c_write(a, b, c, d)   twi_write(a, b, d, c)`) already existed in the code, so I assumed something similar could be replicated.

Comment: The * before data_ptr is his concern.

Comment: @technosaurus Removing the * does not change the initial error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more readable and correct way to write the macro.
It will work in all cases of `if/else` clauses and the struct is defined within a scope so it's name is local and doesn't pollute your name space.

```
#define i2c_write(_slave_addr, _reg_addr, _len, _data_ptr)  \
    do {                                                    \
    twi_packet_t temp = {                                   \
        .addr = _reg_addr,                                  \
        .addr_length = 1,                                   \
        .buffer = _data_ptr,                                \
        .length = _len,                                     \
        .chip = _slave_addr };                              \
                                                            \
    twi_master_write(MPU_TWI, &temp);                       \
    } while (0)
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing it like that!  Just out of interest, do you know what's wrong with my initial attempt?

Comment: You didn't perform the needed cast+reference. you also used `*` on data_ptr.

Comment: FYI, using an anonymous struct will not work well in Visual Studio - at least in the older versions.

Comment: do while 0? huh?

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick It's a clever (if somewhat awkward) way of ensuring that a) the code is executed only once, and b) the expressions stay scoped correctly: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/misc-technical-issues#macros-with-multi-stmts

Comment: @JoshuaHyatt Why not `if(1) { ... }`?

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick As I understand, part of the reason is for consistency. A `do { ... } while(false)` will throw an error if you don't put a semicolon after the macro, where an `if (true) { ... }` won't care.

Comment: @JoshuaHyatt Oh _yeah_, good point. `if(1) { ... }` doesn't enforce the use of semicolons after procedural macro calls.

Answer (score 4):

My take on it, in a compilable sample. This is a compilation stub and **will not run correctly**, so don't try to run it as-is !

```
//
// Cobbling up a compilation stub
//

#include <stdint.h>

struct Twi;
typedef struct Twi Twi;

#define MPU_TWI (Twi*)0

typedef struct twi_packet {
    uint8_t addr[3];
    uint32_t addr_length;
    void *buffer;
    uint32_t length;
    uint8_t chip;
} twi_packet_t;

uint32_t twi_master_write(Twi *p_twi, twi_packet_t *p_packet);


//
// Now for my answer :
//

#define i2c_write(slave_addr, reg_addr, len, data_ptr) \
    twi_master_write(MPU_TWI, &(twi_packet_t){         \
        .addr = reg_addr,                              \
        .addr_length = 1,                              \
        .buffer = *data_ptr,                           \
        .length = len,                                 \
        .chip = slave_addr                             \
    })

main()
{
    // Trigger that macro !
    i2c_write(0, 0, 0, (void**)0);
}
```

This instanciates a *compound literal* and passes its address to the function. The literal's lifetime does not exceed that of the full call expression.

Comment: Despite throwing a warning at every use of `i2c_write`, this compiles fine with no errors!  Edit: Nice stub!

Comment: @MTCoster I edited it in the meantime I guess. Now [GCC 4.8.1](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php) compiles fine with `-Wall -Wextra` :)

Comment: @this It's just a compilation stub, don't ever run that. While GCC is free to do anything with it in optimization phase (Nasal Demons and all), compilation goes smoothly.

Comment: Sooner or later someone will run that.

Comment: @this I can't provide valid parameters anyway (don't have the function definition), and this is out of the Question's scope, but I'll add a bigger disclaimer just in case :p

Comment: @Quentin It's very unlikely that this would ever run correctly on a desktop machine.  `i2c_master_write` is part of the TWI service from ASF for the ATSAM4E series of ARM microcontrollers.

Comment: @MTCoster a little paranoia doesn't hurt and... repels downvotes from other paranoiacs :p

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you provide a simple complete set of a code, so that we can execute here and help you. Meanwhile, i dont think you can use the '*' in the macro, since, macro patameters are not typed. What macro does is just a substitution of a symbol.

Comment: The code I'm working with forms part of a driver library for a motion controller from [InvenSense](http://www.invensense.com).  From the porting guide: [imgur](http://i.imgur.com/YHYXN0x.png).  The complete set of code is a 16Mb package - a bit impractical to post here.