# How to pass unnamed struct in Objective-C protocol method?

Tags: objective-c, struct, protocols

Given the example objective C protocol below:

```objectivec
@protocol testp
- (void)testMethod:(struct {int a;})arg1 reply:(void (^)(NSError *))arg2;
@end
```

Assuming I've already setup the protocol connection. How can I call the method? The issue is the struct type, I'm familiar with passing basic arguments like `int` or `NSString`, however I'm unsure how to handle the unnamed struct in the protocol.

If I use:

```objectivec
struct {  int a; } test = {1};
[p testMethod:test reply:^(NSError* error ){
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```

I get the following error:

`error: sending 'struct (unnamed struct at .. to parameter of incompatible type 'struct (unnamed struct at ..`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call a function that takes an anonymous struct in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66497337/how-do-i-call-a-function-that-takes-an-anonymous-struct-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anonymous struct declared in the method signature..

```objc
 - (void)testMethod:(struct { int a; })arg1 reply:(void (^)(NSError *))arg2;
```

..and in front of the invocation..

```objc
struct {  int a; } test = { 1 };
```

..are two different structures, which are not compatible. For anonymous structures one option you may employ is to pass a pointer to a struct, like this:

```objc
 - (void)method:(struct { int a; } *)str reply:(void (^)(NSError *))arg2;
...
struct { int a; } val = { 1 };
[obj method:&val reply:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```

It should compile, probably with warning about incompatible pointers, but will work just fine as long as the memory layout matches. This approach is very fragile and unreliable, however, and I can't see any reason to not use a named structure:

```objc
typedef struct {
    int val;
} TDWStruct;

@protocol TDWReplyable <NSObject>

- (void)method:(TDWStruct)str reply:(void (^)(NSError *))arg2;

@end

...

TDWStruct val = { 1 };
[obj method:val reply:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```